# my ubuntu 15.04 crashed and I made it worse, but that is not the question

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, thunderbird

Background, my ubuntu will only boot up to command line.  I tried everything to make it go graphical but it just would not work.  I gave up after trying to do things I found on forums for two days and it getting worse.
I made another partition and did a clean install, now everything is working fine in the new Kubuntu.  My question is, I can still go into the old partition and copy files and place them on the new partition.  How do I get my thunderbird files for both emails and calendar?
I do have an external hard drive that I have deja vu back ups on, but am not sure how that will work out since it was ubuntu and this is kubuntu???
If I can just let thunderbird open files from the other partition, that would be better.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply another linux partition (on same phys drive), just [mount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount) the partition '[read-only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal)'. It can also be ['chroot'-ed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) though, I don't see you needing this.

For restoring individual software settings/etc you need to search for those individually. Most of what you need will simply be in your /home/(yourname) directory.
 NOTE:
**BACKUP your NEW /home/* area before starting any file copy/replace.
(Or anywhere else you restore to.)**

Example:

```
sudo tar -cvpzf new_home_backup_defaults.tar.gz /home
```

#### Thunderbird - data restore

Thunderbird [linux default data location](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Linux_and_Unix).

It says folder name can be different depending on version.
So try this:

- Close Thunderbird and open a shell cli ('Konsole' if in KDE)
- In filemanager locate OLD mounted /home/(username) folder. Unhide hidden files.
- Look for `.mozilla-thunderbird` OR `.thunderbird`
- COPY entire hidden folder to new /home/(username)/ in Konsole based on above.

   Example: `cp -r /mnt/oldpartition/home/(username)/.mozilla-thunderbird ~`
- Start Thunderbird.

#### Other application settings:

If you see other apps not setup, slowly/carefully start restoring settings (hidden ".{appname}" files or folders normally) from your OLD /home/(yourname) folder to the new one. This is probably the best place to start. (For instance '~/.mozilla' are user Firefox settings). DO NOT BLINDLY COPY ALL FILES - be especially careful with your X/startx/display manager settings.

#### Kubunut Vs Ubuntu

[There is no difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) between ubunutu and kubuntu in regards to where your /home/* folders are. EDIT: You added to your question - technically, yes, you could configure individual software from old partition data but why? Just copy the "hidden dotfiles" to your new partition /home. [Kubuntu is just a KDE desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives) instead of Gnome. Same overall distribution, different [Display Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Display_Manager) (KDM) and desktop environment (KDE) by default.

#### Your old partition backup

Personally, I would just backup the OLD partition assuming there is no damage or missing files - then just restore from that ***as needed*** (again, mounting backup as  read-only). Also, before restoring any /home/ files, backup your new /home/(yourname) area. (Or anywhere else you touch via restore)

After backup is verified and depending on partition, you can also EITHER [resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition) your new Kubuntu partition to use that partition as well (wipes it out), OR use the old partition as a new mount point - you can safely clear all data from it as you have a tested backup to restore things from.

---