# How can I access windows 10 partition in ubuntu when i cant get it to shut down in a "safe state"?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

i am having a problem with trying to access my windows 10 partition from ubuntu, getting the error:

> ```
> Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/jacob/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/jacob/OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14:
> ```
>
> Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
>       Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
>       The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
>       Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>       read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

I have tried doing a "safe" shutdown many times. (shut down from start menu)

Comment: Try disabling hibernation in windows or try mounting it as read only (if you dont want to write stuff ), try - http://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal

Comment: I believe you have to shut down windows from the command line. 'shutdown -f' If I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot into Windows
2. Disable fast startup
3. [shutdown /s](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/shutdown-command.htm) for a regular shutdown.

---

You can also perform a full shutdown by running this command in a cmd:

```
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

If you can't access Windows, boot into Windows recovery media (DVD) and then run the above command.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sda1
```

also try without `-d` flag

Comment: this is the only solution that worked in my case.

Comment: Life saver! I was booting bear metal from a VHDX with Windows 10 and it blue-screen on me, this fixed it from ubuntu live.