# How to copy files downloaded in ubuntu to windows partitions?

Tags: windows-10

I have downloaded some stuff on ubuntu and want to copy it to my Windows drives in ubuntu, but I don't get the paste option when I right-click on the Windows partition in ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access windows partition from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806570/cannot-access-windows-partition-from-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

1. First let me say that mounting the Windows C: drive in Ubuntu, and then trying to manipulate Windows directories from Ubuntu, can cause Windows problems. Bad idea.
2. Do NOT install any Windows drivers that say they'll let you read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions. It WILL corrupt your Ubuntu partitions.
3. The BEST way to move files between Ubuntu and Windows is to create an extra NTFS partition on your hard disk. Place files to be shared into a directory there, and you can access them from either OS.
4. Another way to move files is to copy them to a USB pen/flash drive, and then you can easily access them from either OS.