# Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it “is in an unsafe state” (don't want to disable fast start)

Tags: boot

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/xxx/6C0AAD330AACFAEA: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/xxx/6C0AAD330AACFAEA"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

I know this is same question as in
[Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state)
[How can I access windows 10 partition in ubuntu when i cant get it to shut down in a "safe state"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693549/how-can-i-access-windows-10-partition-in-ubuntu-when-i-cant-get-it-to-shut-down)

But I don't want to disable fast startup in windows.  How can I solve the issue?

This solution suggested doesn't work.
"

1. Boot to Windows
2. Restart
3. Boot to Ubuntu

"

I don't know what "sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY" does, and I want to try mount it readonly (I actually only want to mount it readonly).  But I can't get it working:
$ sudo mount -t "ntfs" -o uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,ro /dev/sdb1 /media/xxx/6C0AAD330AACFAEA
ntfs-3g-mount: failed to access mountpoint /media/xxx/6C0AAD330AACFAEA: No such file or directory

In the GUI, it doesn't complain about the mount point, when I run it in the cmd line, it complained about non exist mount point. How to solve this particular issue?

I should have something under /media/xxx, but I don't see anything there. What's wrong?

FYI, I am mounting the 2nd hard drive which is not used as windows boot partition and has no windows \user \windows stuffs.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: You should have `/media/xxx` directory to be able to mount there.

Comment: The problem is I have to manually create  /media/xxx/6C0AAD330AACFAEA (which GUI likely created and deleted).  Now the problem is with 'ro' option, it doesn't look like it's read only:  $ ls -l /media/xxx/6C0AAD330AACFAEA/data/
total 196
drwxrwxrwx 1 xxx xxx   8192 Oct 16  2018 audio

Answer (score 2):

You fight against the system, but it will be in vane.

- Fast start in MS Windows does not fully closes file system, as one of the measures taken to allow fast resume, leaving these potentially in a "dirty" state.
- Linux will *not* by default mount a volume that is in a "dirty" state.

Thus, you will not be able to mount the drive in Linux if you insist on holding on to "fast start" in Windows. Before mounting the drive in Linux, make sure any other operating system that has worked with it before, has properly closed the drive. One way to ensure that Windows closes it properly is to turn off "Fast resume".

As you indicate a read-only mount would be OK, you can mount manually:

- Make a mount point, e.g. `sudo mkdir /media/xxx/Windows`
- Mount the drive read only: `sudo mount -t ntfs -o recover,ro,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=222 /dev/sdb1 /media/xxx/Windows

The option `recover` will cause the file system to be mounted read only if the drive is unclean. As such, the option `ro` may not be needed: it will cause the partition to be mounted read only anytime, even if the volume is clean. `uid` and `gid` assign the owner and group. The `umask` option sets the permissions of the file system.

If that works, then you may include a corresponding entry in `/etc/fstab` to have the mount performed automatically at startup.

Comment: How is this possible?  The windows PC is shutdown and how can the file system is not closed when OS is shutdown?

Comment: As indicated in my answer, the "Fast resume" feature of MS Windows causes the volume not to be fully closed. "Fast resume" must be turned of so Windows closes down fully and as such disconnects any devices.

Comment: I added information on how to mount that drive read-only as you indicated that would be OK.

Comment: Not sure if anyone noticed my previous comments. I tried to mount ro (readonly), but ls -l shows it's writable.

Comment: You can change that with the dmask option, which I added to the command.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to label partitions, particularly those I do not mount in fstab. Then they mount by the label, not UUID. But do not confuse a label with a mount point you create. I have mixed data & Data which are not the same in Linux.

Force mount, read only (ro), change example with sda3 to your correct NTFS partition:

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda3 /media/windows
```

I still recommend turning fast start up off.

You can mount read only using fstab and that is recommended for the c: partition in all cases. But you still have to have fast start up off to read/write a NTFS shared data partition.

Set windows boot partition Read only in fstab - Morbius1

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2043862

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /WinC ntfs defaults,noauto,ro,umask=227 0 0
```

After Ubuntu has done it's thing, go in and change the umask to 227 which will make the C Drive read only.