# Can mount alter a partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have a dual boot tablet, Android and Win10 are installed on the MMC drive.
I am using linux/xubuntu in order to restore/manage the MMC drive. My goal is to replace the NTFS win10 partition. For some reasons, I cannot access directly to partitions > 8 with my ubuntu and the win10 partition is the 14th one, please look at the picture below.

I use `kpartx -a /dev/mmcblk0` to be able to access separately to each partitions and then being able to access to the win10 partition.

After some tests, I found out after using `kpartx` command, some partitions get mounted. (android partitions) Afterthat, I cannot boot Android anymore.
After installed from scratch the tablet, I used `dd if=/dev/mmcblk0` in order to make a disk image. Then, by using `kpartx` and `cmp`, I saw, partitions are different.

If I disable the auto-mount in my xUbuntu, I don't have any problem anymore.

This means, xUbuntu changes something in one or more partitions when it mounts them. Could you tell me what `mount` could change ?

There are FAT32, NTFS and unknown partitions. When they are auto-mounted, I got some errors. (of course, android and unknown partitions...)

You know, the tablet has a BIOS very sensitive, if something is changed, the BIOS cannot run Android anymore...

[image]

Comment: Your description sounds a little confusing to me. First you mention Android and Windows 10, and then you talk about Ubuntu and Xubuntu. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: And, if you don't want mount to alter your partitions, you can mount them as read-only (e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal)).

Comment: I edited my question, I use ubuntu only for repairing or managing. (ubuntu,xubuntu are same to me) Actually, I don't want to mount them, how `mount` alters the partition if mounted with `read-write` ? Thanks.

Comment: One simple example: whenever you read a file from a partition mounted as read-write, you also update its access time (which is metadata associated to this file). It's harder to modify the contents of a file without explicit intention, but (X)Ubuntu starts several background processes upon its initialization/boot, and you can never be 100% sure they won't touch your files.