# Bash scripting: my script deletes a working folder prematurely. How do i fix?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

my script works for a single file perfectly, but if I process multiple files, it deletes my workingfolder too early, and only one file is processed. If I don't delete the workingfolder, the script works with multiple files. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /storage/sort_tv/
mkdir workingfolder
for i in *.mp4;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
sudo ffmpeg -i "$i" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:a -map 0:v "workingfolder/${i%.*}.mp4" &&
mv -f workingfolder/* /storage/sort_tv
rm -rf workingfolder
done
```

How can I get all files to be processed AND moved before the working folder is removed?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? And why `rm -rf` instead of `rm -r`?

Comment: Just out of habit. For years I've always used rm -rf. I know its technically not correct.

Comment: It's not wrong, as such, just unnecessarily dangerous since you might be missing useful error messages or deleting write-protected files. The `sudo` is the one you should really avoid: that is creating files you don't own. And a generally good habit to get into is to _never_ use `sudo` unless it is necessary.

Comment: Technically not correct is not the issue. if you have mounts/ hard links (not sure about the latter, but I know for sure that hard links do traverse blocks) on a dual boot system, you can say toodle-oo to your windows partition. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354555/i-just-deleted-everything-on-my-windows-system-through-the-ubuntu-subsystem-can/1354571#1354571) is what `rm -rf` will do for you. I highly doubt that is what you were shooting for. And that is just from a couple of weeks ago. It just happened to be in my history.

Answer (score 4):

You can try moving the rm commands out of the loop. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /storage/sort_tv/
mkdir workingfolder
for i in *.mp4;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
sudo ffmpeg -i "$i" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:a -map 0:v "workingfolder/${i%.*}.mp4" &&
done
mv -f workingfolder/* /storage/sort_tv
rm -rf workingfolder
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it working!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, @Alfke! If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the question solved so others wont waste time on it. Have a nice day