# sudo password on wsl2 Linux on windows 10

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just started using WSL2 (ubuntu 20.04) on Windows 10. If I want to run makefiles or basic stuff like deleting a directory I get" you do not have permission" and then I have to use sudo constantly. What can I configure to avoid this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You should have the permission to do what you like without using `sudo` inside your home directory. Maybe you use a wrong directory. Please [edit] your question and show the command(s) and the current working directory that requires using `sudo`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable root login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:*

Don't do that.  If a file or directory is in a location that your user doesn't have access to without `sudo`, there's a good reason for it, and a normal user shouldn't change the file without understanding the consequences.

*Explanation:*

As mentioned in the comments, your regular user should *not* have permission to access "system files", to attempt to reduce the chance of accidental damage to the system as well as intentional damage (from malware).

If a command is requiring `sudo`, then it's likely that you are in a location where it's *not* safe for you to be creating or deleting files or directories.

For instance:

```
cd /
mkdir project
```

This would require `sudo`, since the root folder of the system is off-limits.  Yes, this is different from Windows, where a normal user *can* create directories at the root level of the drive.

There are very few places that a Linux system considers it safe for a normal user to change files:

- Your home directory, also known as `~`, and typical at `/home/<username>`.  You have full permissions here.
- In `/tmp`, you are allowed to create files/directories.  Your user will be the owner of these files.  You may then change (including delete) the files that you own.  However, you may not change *other* users' files in this directory.

  For the most part, files are created in the `/tmp` directory by *applications* (processes) that need temporary files (similar to `C:\Users\<youruser>\AppData\Local\Temp` in Windows).  You really shouldn't need to create files there yourself.

In addition to those two, WSL has additional locations that your normal Ubuntu user will be able to change.  By default, your user will own the `/mnt/c/` mount (and other drives) that WSL creates for you to access Windows drives.

This means that you can (but probably shouldn't):

```
cd /mnt/c/
mkdir me_my_and_i
```

However, the fact that your Ubuntu user has *Linux* permissions to files on this drive doesn't mean that you have unlimited access.  WSL is still a *Windows* application, running with your *Windows* user's permissions.  So you *cannot* (even with `sudo`) change files in (for instance) `C:\Windows\` and other sensitive (system) locations.

This prevents an accidental or malicious command in Ubuntu from destroying your Windows installation.   ***Please note*** that you can [still do a massive amount of damage to your Windows installation](https://askubuntu.com/q/1354555/1165986) even with these protections in place.  But the system will at least still be bootable.

---

Going back to the topic of the *Ubuntu* locations, you should understand that you *can* create new directories (using `sudo` once) in places you really *shouldn't* and then give your regular user ownership of that directory.  With that in place, you would have created a new location where your user has permissions to change files without needing `sudo`.  For instance:

```
# Not recommended, for example only
cd /

# won't work, permission denied:
mkdir me_myself_and_i

# Use sudo:
sudo mkdir me_myself_and_i
sudo chown <yourusername>:<yourusername> me_myself_and_i
ls -l
# Notice that the directory is owned by you - All others are owned by root

cd my_myself_and_i

# Works *without* sudo:
touch 123
rm 123
```

However, if you try:

```
cd /
rmdir me_myself_and_i
```

You will need `sudo`.  Even though you own `me_myself_and_i`, removing it is a change to the root `/` directory, which `root` still owns (and should).

Conversely, you can even create a directory (or file) inside your own home directory that your user *can't* access:

```
cd ~
sudo mkdir me_myself_and_i
cd me_myself_and_i
touch 123
```

This will result in `Permission denied`, since `root` owns the directory that you just created.

However, your normal user *can* delete the newly created (`root`-owned) directory (as long as it is empty), since you still own your home (the parent) directory.